# Export system of inequalities in MPS format

Tags: export, mathematical-optimization, import, inequalities

I am interested in the `.MPS` format, usually used in Linear Programming problems (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MPS.html)).

When importing a file in the `.MPS` format, Mathematica returns a list

```
{ObjectiveFunction, Constraints, Variables}
```

which can be used with `NMinimize` or `NMaximize` to solve the Linear Programming Problem.

Given an `ObjectiveFunction` and a set of constraints, is it possible to export the system into a file in the format `.MPS` ready to be imported in another computer?